Does there exists something like the BKK Theorem for polynomials over finite fields?
I'm trying to count the number of common $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$-zeros of some polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{F}_q[x,y]$. I thought I had a solution using the BKK theorem but I reread the theorem statement and was disappointed to realize that it seems to only apply to polynomials over the complex numbers. I was wondering if there are some similar results to the BKK theorem that apply in the context finite field. Or, if the BKK theorem would apply in this context? Although, I doubt that as I couldn't find anything online. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have never heard of anything called the BKK theorem. Please explain! Anyway, Gröbner bases / resultants might help here. And at some point calculate the gcd with $x^q-x$ and/or $y^q-y$ to force the solutions into $\Bbb{F}_q$.

@JyrkiLahtonen BKK Theorem (Wikipedia). It essential just state that given a set of generic polynomials $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ with a finite number of common zeroes, then the number of common zeroes is the normalized mixed volume of their corresponding Newton polytopes. I may have just butchered that so the Wikipedia link is probably the way to go. The book Using Algebraic Geometry seems to provide a nice proof (they call it Bernstein's theorem). I'll look into Gröbner bases and resultants, thank you!

Thanks for sharing, @Amelia! Somehow I had managed not to learn about BKK. I need to look up more details when I get to our library. For the moment I'm still mystified. And also mildly worried about the roles played by the proviso of generic polynomials and the fact that $\Bbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. For me solutions of polynomial system over finite fields have been an extension number theoretic systems, with solutions constrained to be integers modulo a prime. True, the underlying geometry plays a huge role (Weil conjectures), and your question is about zero-dimensional algebraic sets.
